# Get the minimum value of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get the minimum value of this array.
I am using `array_maps` and running it with `for` and can't find what I want.

```
$des['PICO']['new'] = 98;
$des['PICO']['old'] = 100;

$des['ALTO']['new'] = 101;
$des['ALTO']['old'] = 110;

$des['BAI']['new'] = 96;
$des['BAI']['old'] = 102;

$min_new = null;
$min_old = null;
$min_key = null;

foreach($des as $key => $value){

   if($min_new < $value['new']){

      $min_new = $value['new'];
      $min_old = $value['old'];
      $min_key = $key;
    }  
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting and what is the expected output?

Comment: Is there any progress with this?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are starting your min value at null.  This will mean that none of the values are less than that.  So start it at the highest int and only store the key value for use later...

```
$min_new = PHP_INT_MAX;
$min_key = null;

foreach($des as $key => $value){
    if($min_new > $value['new']){
        $min_new = $value['new'];
        $min_key = $key;
    }
}

print_r($des[$min_key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $des['PICO']['new'] = 98;
    $des['PICO']['old'] = 100;
    $des['ALTO']['new'] = 101;
    $des['ALTO']['old'] = 110;
    $des['BAI']['new'] = 96;
    $des['BAI']['old'] = 102;
    $min_new = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $min_old = PHP_INT_MAX;
    $min_key = PHP_INT_MAX;

    foreach($des as $key => $value){
       if($min_new > $value['new']){
          $min_new = $value['new'];
        }
       if($min_old > $value['old']){
          $min_old = $value['old'];
        }
       if($min_key > $min_new ){
          $min_key = $min_new;
        }
       if($min_key > $min_old ){
          $min_key = $min_old;
        }
    }
    echo "n=". $min_new . " o=" . $min_old . " k=" . $min_key;
    ?>
```

or

```
    foreach($des as $key => $value){

       if($min_new > $value['new']){
          $min_new = $value['new'];
          $min_key = $key;
        }
       if($min_old > $value['old']){
          $min_old = $value['old'];
          $min_key = $key;
        }
    }
    echo "n=". $min_new . " o=" . $min_old . " k=" . $min_key;
```

Output:
n=96 o=100 k=BAI